# Is sending '200 OK' status code after POST method call violates HTTP/REST principle?

Tags: rest, http

Scenario:

1. A client calls POST HTTP method with needed information in the message body.
2. Server sucessfully creates the resource. But there is no way to refer to created resource via direct link.

What is the best way to answer the client, that its request was successfully processed?

a) return 201 (but no Location Header provided).

b) simply return 200 without any additional information.

c) some other option...

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your statement that a resource is created but that no link to that resource will be available. The definition of a resource is something that can be named as its own independent entity and that is addressed by one or multiple URIs. Note that HTTP is just a remote document management protocol and as such it isn't designed for batch stuff in mind as it treats each request as a document to manage at the server side and any business rules you conclude are just a side effect of that document management. See [Webber 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=191s)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be a REST purist, then the proper response here would be to return a 201 with the URL to the newly created resource in the Location header in the response.

An HTTP 201 status code means 'Created' and the Location header is meant to be set in one of two scenarios, one of those being to provide information about a newly created resource:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

Comment: Thanks, but this not quite the answer I was looking for. Returning URL is not an option - I have mentioned that.

Comment: Ah, sorry, just read that.  So you are creating a resource that can never be accessed?

Comment: I mentioned that "no way to refer to created resource via direct(!) link". There are possibilities to use the resource later, but in some specific context. Only no way to refer to it separately.

Comment: Yeah I think you're sort of in a scenario outside of the norm.  I would return a 201 with an empty location header in your instance, but that's just my highly uneducated opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, while the question was open, I found the answer which is:

> The action performed by the POST method might not result in a resource
>   that can be identified by a URI. In this case, either 200 (OK) or 204
>   (No Content) is the appropriate response status, depending on whether
>   or not the response includes an entity that describes the result.

[copied from](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

So in short, NO - this not violates anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the appropriate response code for each appropriate situation.

- If your POST API was successful and a resource was created, you'd better return 201 because 201 means the creation of a resource.
- If your POST API was successful but any resource was not created, you'd better return 200 or 204 because your API didn't create any new resource.